# Is it possible the Windows can be login like Linux using command?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

Is it possible the Windows can be login like Linux using command?

We know the Linux we can use command login, so we can use a script realize a function, such as:

```
login the Linux -> change root password.
```

this is easy by realize use bash script.

But can Windows Server be controled like Linux?

the script login the Windows and execute the bat script to the Windows Server.

Comment: In theory and mostly in practice too, all core  Windows tasks can be scripted with PowerShell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can do that. Similar thread on SuperUser community:

https://superuser.com/questions/15596/automatically-run-a-script-when-i-log-on-to-windows